# Al ejecutar un código a través de un botón este no deja de ejecutarse y continúa realizando su acción

Tags: android, firebase

Lo que pasa es que tengo un layout que muestra info de un usuario, sin embargo, tengo un código en el cual al darle click a este layout, este elimina la info del usuario en la base de datos de Firebase y este en vez de eliminar una vez los datos del usuario, continúa eliminando los datos aunque ya hayan sido eliminados, y en la base de datos muestra que sigue eliminando los datos como si siguiera ejecutando el código...

Este es el código:

```
    ly1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //Dialogo de alerta
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setMessage("¿Quieres eliminar esta información?")
                            .setTitle("Consulta")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    })
                            .setPositiveButton("Sí, continuar",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                            eliminar1();

                                        }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    //Dialogo de alerta
                }
            });

        public void eliminar1(){
                Database.child("users").addValueEventListener(
                        new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.child(user_id).exists()) {
                                    DatabaseReference UserDB = Database.child("users").child(user_id);
                                    UserDB.child("País1").removeValue();
                                    UserDB.child("Ciudad1").removeValue();
                                    UserDB.child("TipodeEmpresa1").removeValue();
                                    UserDB.child("UserEmp1").removeValue();
                                    UserDB.child("TipoAtencion1").removeValue();
                                    UserDB.child("Numero1").removeValue();
                                    UserDB.child("Direccion1").removeValue();
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
Database.child("users empresas").addValueEventListener(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(user_id).exists()) {
                            DatabaseReference EUserDB = Database.child("users empresas").child(user_id);
                            EUserDB.child("País1").removeValue();
                            EUserDB.child("Ciudad1").removeValue();
                            EUserDB.child("TipodeEmpresa1").removeValue();
                            EUserDB.child("UserEmp1").removeValue();
                            EUserDB.child("TipoAtencion1").removeValue();
                            EUserDB.child("Numero1").removeValue();
                            EUserDB.child("Direccion1").removeValue();

                            DatabaseReference EmpUserDB = Database.child("Empresas " + País).child(Ciudad)
                                    .child(TipodeEmpresa).child(user_id);
                            EmpUserDB.child("País1").removeValue();
                            EmpUserDB.child("Ciudad1").removeValue();
                            EmpUserDB.child("TipodeEmpresa1").removeValue();
                            EmpUserDB.child("UserEmp1").removeValue();
                            EmpUserDB.child("TipoAtencion1").removeValue();
                            EmpUserDB.child("Numero1").removeValue();
                            EmpUserDB.child("Direccion1").removeValue();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
        }
```

Esto es lo que ocurre en la Database de Firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el Logcat lo único que me arroja es esto:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 156145(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 42% free, 16MB/28MB, paused 2.699ms total 129.416ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 151397(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 17MB/29MB, paused 3.040ms total 157.930ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 157889(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 18MB/30MB, paused 3.274ms total 148.011ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 156957(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 18MB/31MB, paused 3.453ms total 153.131ms
I/Choreographer: Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 152412(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 19MB/32MB, paused 4.729ms total 160.107ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 150465(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 20MB/33MB, paused 3.861ms total 172.896ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 163116(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 21MB/35MB, paused 4.198ms total 191.875ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 180853(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 22MB/36MB, paused 5.180ms total 194.496ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 186895(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/38MB, paused 4.822ms total 207.796ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 177832(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 4.416ms total 219.217ms
I/Choreographer: Skipped 126 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 186017(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 24MB/40MB, paused 4.827ms total 214.308ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 29.602ms for cause HeapTrim
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 199439(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 38% free, 25MB/41MB, paused 5.155ms total 236.598ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 194731(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 26MB/42MB, paused 5.769ms total 244.224ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 188405(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 36% free, 27MB/43MB, paused 6.586ms total 252.006ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 201791(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 35% free, 28MB/44MB, paused 6.023ms total 262.258ms
I/Choreographer: Skipped 162 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 208883(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 34% free, 29MB/45MB, paused 6.196ms total 268.874ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 203862(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 34% free, 30MB/46MB, paused 7.763ms total 277.918ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 216592(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 33% free, 31MB/47MB, paused 8.465ms total 294.595ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 214939(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 32MB/48MB, paused 7.123ms total 300.286ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 218513(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 34MB/50MB, paused 7.153ms total 314.664ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 213545(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 35MB/51MB, paused 7.591ms total 321.990ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 224874(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 30% free, 36MB/52MB, paused 10.347ms total 352.826ms
I/Choreographer: Skipped 203 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 221543(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 37MB/53MB, paused 7.489ms total 353.758ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 228626(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 38MB/54MB, paused 9.213ms total 373.558ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 238412(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 40MB/56MB, paused 8.436ms total 378.300ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 250041(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 27% free, 41MB/57MB, paused 10.690ms total 395.786ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 229737(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 27% free, 42MB/58MB, paused 10.770ms total 412.705ms
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 242506(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 43MB/59MB, paused 11.316ms total 419.269ms
```

no se me ocurre cuál puede ser el motivo de este error...

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas utilizando un listener de Firebase (`addValueEventListener`) que te avisa cada vez que cambia un valor. Esto hace que cada vez que eliminas una propiedad Firebase te avise y, por lo tanto, se vuelve a ejecutar el código que definiste para borrar las propiedades. Tenes que usar `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. De esa forma escuchas solamente una vez y podes ejecutar el código dentro del listener una sola vez.

Por otro lado, te recomiendo no usar espacios en los nombres de los nodos, si necesitas separar palabras usa `_` en vez de espacios.

Comment: Al parecer ese era el problema, no me ha dado el mismo error por el momento, muchas gracias amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que `Database.child("users")...` es la referencia a users, estas creando una referencia nueva mas abajo que hace lo mismo, entonces estas teniendo un problema de concurrencia

entonces esto `DatabaseReference UserDB = Database.child("users").child(user_id);`

es lo mismo que esto  `Database.child("users").addValue....`

para solucionarlo sacalo y dejalo asi

```
 public void eliminar1(){
                Database.child("users").addValueEventListener(
                        new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.child(user_id).exists()) {

                                    dataSnapshot.child("País1").removeValue();
                                    dataSnapshot.child("Ciudad1").removeValue();
                                    dataSnapshot.child("TipodeEmpresa1").removeValue();
                                    dataSnapshot.child("UserEmp1").removeValue();
                                    dataSnapshot.child("TipoAtencion1").removeValue();
                                    dataSnapshot.child("Numero1").removeValue();
                                    dataSnapshot.child("Direccion1").removeValue();
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
Database.child("users empresas").addValueEventListener(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(user_id).exists()) {

                            dataSnapshot.child("País1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("Ciudad1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("TipodeEmpresa1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("UserEmp1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("TipoAtencion1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("Numero1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("Direccion1").removeValue();

                           Database.child("Empresas " + País).child(Ciudad)
                                    .child(TipodeEmpresa).child(user_id).addValueEventListener(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            dataSnapshot.child("País1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("Ciudad1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("TipodeEmpresa1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("UserEmp1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("TipoAtencion1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("Numero1").removeValue();
                            dataSnapshot.child("Direccion1").removeValue();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Ademas estas creando referencias anidadas adentro de referencias ya creadas, por lo que generas redundancia de valores, asi deberia funcionar me avisas

Comment: Mejoró bastante, pero sigue ocurriendo el error de que aparecen miles de datos en la base de datos, como si el código se ejecutara una y otra vez, a veces creo que es porque envío o elimino muchos datos muy seguido, sin esperar un tiempo necesario... Puede ser esa una razón?

Comment: no, no tiene que ver con el tiempo, lo que pasa es que tienes listeners que escuchan todo el tiempo cambios para ejecutar esos remove, una pregunta, por ejemplo adentro del snapshot users_empresas tienes todos esos campos que pones ahi o esos son algunos ?, podrias poner una foto de la base de datos de esos campos ?

Comment: lo que deberias hacer en vez de tener ciudad 1 , ciudad 2 , ciudad 3 todo bajo un mismo nodo seria tener todas las ciudades 1 abajo de un pushkey, las ciudades 2 abajo de otro y asi con todo, entonces para acceder a los datos de una determinada ciudad te es mucho mas facil y si tienes que borrar todos esos datos solos vas a la referencia y pones removevalue a todo , sin tener que hacerlo por cada uno

Comment: Es buena idea Gastón, pero lo que pasa es que cada ciudad va relacionada con los datos de su mismo número, por ejemplo pais1, ciudad1, etc.

Comment: Al parecer ya se solucionó el problema, con tu ayuda y la de la respuesta de arriba, muchas gracias!

Comment: claro, te entiendo, por cada ciudad podes ponerle adentro el pais, numero y lo que necesitas , entonces acceder a una ciudad podes obtener los datos de la misma sin interconectar nodos ni nada por el estilo, o dejarlos en un mismo lado, vos sabes que siempre que se empieza a diseñar la estructura de una base de datos NoSql hay que sentarse y ver bien como se va a dejar por que despues al ultimo tenes que mover todo jajaja, me paso, de diez que ya lo hayas solucionado, cualquier otra duda consulta :)